# Java - break while with Key in a simple way

Tags: java, while-loop

First, I apologize for my grammar etc, because English is not my main language and I should tell you, it's not that long, since I started programming.

My main problem, is the while loop which you can see down there. If I run this in eclipse it says "type something in" the problem I have is: I type the thing I want... then press Enter and I can type something else. But it should break through the loop. I hope you can tell me an easy way to add this "if key is pressed" -> break through.

Thank you a lot
sincerely Kanubbel

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Anagramm {

    void erzeugen(String eingabe) {
        char[] test = new char[eingabe.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < eingabe.length(); i++) {
            test[i] = eingabe.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String wort1 = "test";
        String wort2 = "test";

        System.out.println("Geben Sie hier Ihr erstes Wort ein:");
        Scanner erstbegriff = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (erstbegriff.hasNext()) {
            wort1 += erstbegriff.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Geben Sie hier Ihr zweites Wort ein:");
        Scanner zweitbegriff = new Scanner(System.in);
        wort2 = zweitbegriff.toString();

        erstbegriff.close();
        zweitbegriff.close();

        String erstesWort = wort1.replace(" ", "");
        String zweitesWort = wort2.replace(" ", "");

        char[] wortEins = erstesWort.toCharArray();
        char[] wortZwei = zweitesWort.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(wortEins);
        Arrays.sort(wortZwei);

        if (Arrays.equals(wortEins, wortZwei)) {
            System.out.println("Es handelt sich um ein Anagramm.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Es handelt sich um kein Anagramm.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't create a new Scanner object, re-use the first one (`erstbegriff `)

Comment: Maybe the Scanner.nextLine() would help for your scenario? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

just add a break statement to the while loop like:

```
 while (erstbegriff.hasNext()) {
        wort1 += erstbegriff.next();
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
while (erstbegriff.hasNext()) {
            wort1 += erstbegriff.next();
}
```

If you just want to read in a single line of input, you can use

`erstbegriff.nextLine()` instead

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the while loop there.
Scanner is already waiting for an input. This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String wort1 = "test";
    String wort2 = "test";

    System.out.println("Geben Sie hier Ihr erstes Wort ein:");
    Scanner erstbegriff = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (erstbegriff.hasNext()) {
        wort1 += erstbegriff.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Geben Sie hier Ihr zweites Wort ein:");
    if (erstbegriff.hasNext()) {
        wort2 += erstbegriff.next();
    }

    erstbegriff.close();

    String erstesWort = wort1.replace(" ", "");
    String zweitesWort = wort2.replace(" ", "");

    char[] wortEins = erstesWort.toCharArray();
    char[] wortZwei = zweitesWort.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(wortEins);
    Arrays.sort(wortZwei);

    if (Arrays.equals(wortEins, wortZwei)) {
        System.out.println("Es handelt sich um ein Anagramm.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Es handelt sich um kein Anagramm.");
    }
}
```